# Apache Flink и "no more connection allowed (max_client_conn)"

Tags: java, postgresql, apache

Имеется SourceFunction, который извлекает из Postgresql данные и отправляет далее по MapFunction. SourceFunction с parallelism = 1 и MapFunction с parallelism = 100. С недавних времен при инициализации HikariPool стали появляться ошибки

> "no more connection allowed (max_client_conn)"

В ПГ доступно 200 коннектов, и они почти всегда свободны. По идее SourceFunction должен использовать всего одно соединение, так как 1 parallelism.
Почему так происходит и как избавиться от этого? Увеличение коннектов на стороне ПГ не подходит. Его и так много.

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении `ssl=true&sslmode=allow` в конец datasource url ошибка пропала. Вопрос решён.